# Подчиняется ли слово полдник правилу написания слов с первой частью пол

Tags: словообразование, морфология

Подчиняется ли слово полдник правилу написания слов с первой частью пол? Исторически это слово образовано от слова пол.А на современном этапе это слово можно ли разделить на части: пол и дня? Или это уже одно слово? Ведь в нем уже есть суффикс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По правилам слитно пишется слово ***полдня***:  ПОЛДНЯ,  м. Половина дня. Прошло полдня.

От него образуется слово ***полдник***. Схема образования: пол/дня (половина дня) ― пол/дник (наложение суффикса НИК на корень ДН)

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=-&start=15240  Дело в том, что в слове ***полдник*** наблюдается совмещение морфем. Это слово образовано с помощью суффикса -ник, и суффикс как бы накладывается на корень, букву н можно считать и частью корня, и частью суффикса.

Сравнить: праздник ― от порожний (пустой) день.

ПОЛДНИК,  м. Лёгкая еда между обедом и ужином; время такого приёма пищи.

Comment: Схема образования мне известна. Вопрос другой: подчиняется правилу или нет?

Comment: В правиле Розенталя говорится  о  числительном ПОЛ (‘половина’) в составе сложного слова, и это правило относится к существительным (нарицательным и собственным) в форме Р.п. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52  Этому правилу подчиняется слово  "полдня".  В производных словах (полуденный, полулитровый ) корень ПОЛ переходит в корень ПОЛУ и пишется всегда слитно (это уже другое правило). Поэтому на производные слова правило написания  корня ПОЛ не распространяется, это касается и слова "полдник".